# MockMVC not working with server.context-path=/myRoot

Tags: controller, spring-boot, mockmvc

O. 
I am using Spring boot server.context-path=/myRoot. 
Then i have a @RestController that handles @RequestMapping("/some/path"). 
In the controller unit test i am using MockMvc.

```
@Test
    public void shouldGetSuccessfulHttpResponseForBasket() throws Exception {
        //Given
        String requestURL = "/some/path";
        //When
        MvcResult result = getMockMvc().perform(get(requestURL))
        //Then
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
        String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertNotEquals("Content should not be empty", "", content);
    }
```

So my problem is that content is comming empty. It's because my unit test doesn't use the server.context-path=/myRoot. 
So if i use this URL "/myRoot/some/path" the http status is 400 because it doesn't find a matching handler. 
If i use this URL "/some/path" the http status is 200 but content is empty (when it shouldn't).
If i annotate my controller with @RequestMapping("/myRoot"), it works with this URL "/myRoot/some/path". But then my application won't work as i expect. In this last case i will have to use this URL "/myRoot/myRoot/some/path" in order to get a response from my service.

So the ideal solution would be to get rid of server.context-path=/myRoot.
This can't be done because the application depends on that property.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Update:

This is my base class. My test class is extending this one.

```
/**
 * Sets up and gets the mvc test support available in the mock context.
 */
public abstract class MvcTestCase {

    /** The spring mock web context. */
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webContext;

    /**
     * The service that creates a mock context to test against the front Controller.
     */
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    /**
     * Sets up the service that creates a mock context to test against the front Controller.
     * 
     * @throws Exception thrown when set up fails.
     */
    @Before
    public void setupMockContext() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webContext)
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the mock mvc test support.
     * 
     * @return The entry point for server-side Spring MVC test support.
     */
    public MockMvc getMockMvc() {
        return mockMvc;
    }

}
```

Comment: what does getMockMvc() do? are you using MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup? Also it would be useful to see what annotations you have on your test class.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Sorry, i forgot to mention that. My test class is extending a class that builds the MockMvc.

Comment: You should be able to ignore the context path completely in your tests. IMO, you should focus on figuring out why the response's content is empty. What does the controller mapped to `/some/path` do?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The response's content is empty because "there is not handler for that URL". This is because my handler is dependant on the server.context-path property.